# Salesforce (Visualforce): the view isn't well synchronized with the controller

Tags: jquery, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I'm using a visualforce page to fill a score for a set of questions. The controller contains a map that holds those values and save them to the Database after a save button is clicked.

The problem is on the first click on the button the lines are not properly saved. But when i click for the second time, everything is magically well saved.

I can't figure out what is the problem.

Tnx 4 ur help.

Comment: Post some code like the save method and the commandButton (or whatever it is) that's a relevant piece of Visualforce. Does whole page refresh or do you rerender only a piece?

Answer (score 1):

I see you tagged your question with jquery tag in which case @RemoteAction should work fine.

Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the maps in the visualforce page, I was using an apex:repeat on a map and for each map value I use another repeat on another map.

I've been told that the maps aren't stable enough in Visualforce, so I used a list of a wrapper class instead, it's not an optimal solution but it solved the problem.

Thanks 4 ur help.

Regards,